# In a noetherian ring there are only finitely many minimal prime ideals containing a given ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Why in any noetherian ring $N$ there are only finitely many minimal prime ideals containing an ideal $I$ given?

I know that every ideal in $N$ is finitely many generated but I don´t  know how use this fact to get the answer. Thank for any help!

Comment: That's not true: $\Bbb Z$ is Noetherian yet has infinitely many prime ideals containing the zero ideal.

Comment: I have to write minimal ideals, thanks!

Comment: @AnginaSeng Just as a note, zero itself is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ so the only minimal prime over zero is zero.

Answer (score 7):

In a Noetherian ring, each ideal is a finite intersection of primary ideals:
$$I=Q_1\cap\cdots\cap Q_k.$$
If $P$ is a prime ideal containing $I$ then $P\supseteq Q_i$
for some $I$. Therefore $P=\sqrt P\supseteq \sqrt{Q_i}$. The ideal
$\sqrt Q_i$ is prime. So the minimal prime ideals containing $I$
are some of the $\sqrt{Q_i}$.

Comment: This is a long time after you answered, but how do you know that $\sqrt{Q_i}$ itself is minimal?

Comment: I don't: possibly some are not, but all the minimal members of the set of prime ideals  containing $I$ are of the form $\sqrt{Q_i}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Another proof**, based on the topological properties of $\operatorname{Spec}N$:

First, observe that, since $N/I$ is noetherian and there's a bijection between the (minimal) prime ideals of $N/I$ and the (minimal) prime ideals of $N$ which contain $I$,  it is enough to prove the finiteness of the minimal prime ideals of $N$.

Second, there's a bijection between the set of minimal prime ideals of $N$ and the set of *irreducible components* of the topological space $\operatorname{Spec}N$:
$$\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Min} N\longleftrightarrow V(\mathfrak p)=\{\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec}N\mid \mathfrak p\subset \mathfrak q\}. $$
Last: since $N$ is noetherian ring, $\operatorname{Spec}N$ is a noetherian space, i.e. every non-increasing sequence of closed sets in $\operatorname{Spec}N$ stabilises, and a noetherian space has a finite number of irreducible components.